# How to combine multiple rows with the same index with each row have only one true value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe which has the following shape:

```
                          OPEN_INT PX_HIGH PX_LAST VOL
timestamp  ticker source     
2018-01-01   AAPL   NYSE         1      NaN    NaN NaN
2018-01-01   AAPL   NYSE       NaN        2    NaN NaN
2018-01-01   AAPL   NYSE       NaN      NaN      3 NaN
2018-01-01   AAPL   NYSE       Nan      NaN    NaN   4
2018-01-01   MSFT   NYSE         5      NaN    NaN NaN
2018-01-01   MSFT   NYSE       NaN        6    NaN NaN
2018-01-01   MSFT   NYSE       NaN      NaN      7 NaN
2018-01-01   MSFT   NYSE       Nan      NaN    NaN   8
```

In each column for each (timestamp, ticker, source) group there is gurantted only one value, all other values are Nan, is there any way I can combine these into single rows so it looks like:

```
                          OPEN_INT PX_HIGH PX_LAST VOL
timestamp  ticker source     
2018-01-01   AAPL   NYSE         1      2        3   4
2018-01-01   MSFT   NYSE         5      6        7   8
```

I have tried to use `df.groupby(['timestamp', 'ticker', 'source']).agg(lambda x: x.dropna()` but I got an error saying `Function does not reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.groupby(['timestamp', 'ticker', 'source']).first()
```

If is always only one value per groups aggregate by `max`, `min`, `sum`, `mean`...:

```
df.groupby(['timestamp', 'ticker', 'source']).max()
```